# Yun - replaced uhttpd with lighttpd - luci works but not /data access..?

Tags: arduino-yun

Ok, utthpd is running on port 80 and lighttpd on port 81...both give access to the luci control panel...all well and good.

However the /data access to the yun data store only works from uhttpd.

Lighttpd returns error 404 (page not found).

Any idea what the solution might be..?